# View lose click listener after animation with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, objectanimator

I have a recycler view in the lower half of the screen where if you click on an item, that item gets animated to the top of the screen using `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, View.TRANSLATION_Y, yDelta)` (the recycle view has `parent.clipChildren = false` so that the item can move outside of the recycler view). This all lives inside a `RelativeLayout`  with `match_parent` on `width` and `height`.

No clicks are registered on the item ones it's outside of its parent recycler view (which in all honesty feels reasonable). How can I go about making the item still register clicks outside its parent?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: Since I always animate my item to the top of the screen, I was able to put a `View` who's always at the top, that covers the animated item. That way the user thinks he's tapping on the item but instead he's tapping on the dummy view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to increase size of my view, there is no way to listen clicks outside parent view